# Lenovo IdeaPad Z580 Super Hot after Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, laptop, lenovo, overheating, ideapad

So I have a Z580 laptop which has ONLY Ubuntu 12.04 installed,
It has a i3 Processor with Intel and Nvidia Cards and 4GB RAM,
The problem is even if I run no apps, It gets heated up?
I removed Windows 7 completely while Installing Ubuntu.....
BTW My Nvidia Card is a GeForce with Cuda
Can Somebody Please Help Me?
EDIT: I found out that installing drivers for your card is a solution but I installed NVIDIA Drivers from the additional driver menu, but I really don't feel any change....

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these commands and keep the setting as conservative.

```
sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils cpufreqd 
sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq
```

Also install bumblebee for better control over your graphics card. Click [here](http://www.askmeaboutlinux.com/?p=2360) for more information